# set as default app not working

Tags: android, android-listview, android-contacts, intentfilter

I want to set my custom contactlist app on system phonebook i am using below code but its not working

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.contacts.list.rotate.sms.colored.phonebook.free.TestActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
             <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.APP_CONTACTS" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>


    </activity>
```

Help me whats wrong with this code thanks in advance

Comment: An "not working" means, exactly, what?

Comment: How is it "Not working" - Got a logcat? Any debug info? What does the app do? @Aleks G - Beat me to it!

Comment: Should work in portrait orientation. You tried ?

Comment: Sir i have created an phonebook app i want to set it as defualt phonebook , it first ask from user if user select "Set as default" then myphonebook is open whenever user click on phonebook icon of system

Answer (score 0):

android.intent.category.DEFAULT is used to declare some operation as default action (as its name suggest). Lets consider we have a notepad app(referring to android notepad sample). The first page of app consists of a list of all notepad files. When one notepad file is selected one of the operations like edit note, delete note etc can be performed. But I want to make edit as my default action which means when i press center button of my keypad,edit window should be open.

Replacing system phonebook app with custom app is not possible as Andorid Phonebook app is an embedded app. It can not be removed but if your device is rooted then you can do this as below.

1. First remove the system phonebook app.
2. install/push your app in system.